# If $x \in \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}{E_n \cup F_n}$, can $x \in F_n$ for infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Context:

[image]

I wasn't sure if it was valid to consider the case where $x \in F_n$ for infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$ because my intuition tells me that $x \in \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}{E_n \cup F_n} \implies  $ $x \in F_n$ for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Otherwise, if $x \in F_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then I would imagine that $x \in E_n\cup F_n $ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

My question comes down to this:

Is it true that $x \in \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}{E_n \cup F_n} \implies  $ $x \in E_n$ for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $x \in F_n$ for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (and not infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$)?

---

My attempt at disproving this:

Let $E_n = \begin{cases} 
\{1,2,3\} & n = 1 \\
\{1,2\} & n \geq 2 \\ \end{cases}$ 
and $F_n = \begin{cases} 
\{4,5\} & n = 1 \\
\{4\} & n \geq 2 \\ \end{cases}$.

Then clearly $4 \in F_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ but is also in $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}E_n\cup F_n$. So the claim is false.

Now I suspect that this example I constructed is inadequate as in this case, the limit clearly exists and so $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} E_n\cup F_n = \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} E_n\cup F_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} E_n\cup F_n $.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be totally off, but from what you wrote is seems to me that you do not correctly understand the phrase "all but finitely many", in regards to natural indices $n$.

That phrase means "all natural numbers, with the exception of only a finite list of natural numbers". So it could mean "all natural numbers" (the exception list is empty), or "all natural numbers greater or equal to $500$" (the exception list would be $0,1,2,\ldots,499$) or "all positive integers that are either prime or have at least 2 digits in decimal representation" (the exception list would be $1,4,6,8,9$).

Not under this definition would fall "all even numbers" (the execption list, the odd numbers, contains infinitly many numbers), or "all prime numbers" (there are infinitely many non-primes).

I came to this conclusion because you first wrote

> ... $\Rightarrow x \in F_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in \mathbb N$. Otherwise,
>   if $x\in F_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, then ...

The opposite ("otherwise") of "for all but finitely many $n\in \mathbb N$" is "for only a finite number of $n\in \mathbb N$", it is **not** "for all $n\in \mathbb N$", as you write.

The same happens later, when you write

> ... $x\in F_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in N$ (and not infinitely
>   many $n\in N$)?

By necessity, if something holds for "all but finitely many $n\in N$", then it must hold for infinitely many $n\in N$, so your requirement in parenthesis is not possible.